# PHP SOAP XML Response convert to DOM Document loadxml() - not working, empty

Tags: php, xml, dom, soap, load

I have a SOAP Response which I want convert to a DOM Document. I am using loadxml() for that, but it returns an empty object.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:getResponse xmlns:ns2="http://api.sponsoredlistings.ask.com/api/v5/"><rval xmlns="http://api.sponsoredlistings.ask.com/api/v5/"><ns2:totalNumEntries>6</ns2:totalNumEntries><ns2:entries><ns2:id>3000063</ns2:id><ns2:name>QA_Team_1</ns2:name><ns2:status>ACTIVE</ns2:status><ns2:servingStatus>Inactive</ns2:servingStatus><ns2:startDate>20100730</ns2:startDate><ns2:endDate>20991231</ns2:endDate><ns2:budget><ns2:period>MONTHLY</ns2:period><ns2:amount><ns2:amount>3333.3333</ns2:amount></ns2:amount><ns2:deliveryMethod>STANDARD</ns2:deliveryMethod></ns2:budget><ns2:biddingStrategy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:ManualCPC"/><ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus>OPTIMIZE</ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus><ns2:stats><ns2:network>ALL</ns2:network><ns2:statsType>Stats</ns2:statsType></ns2:stats><ns2:statusReason>FutureDT</ns2:statusReason></ns2:entries><ns2:entries><ns2:id>3000064</ns2:id><ns2:name>Sample Campaign for Itay</ns2:name><ns2:status>ACTIVE</ns2:status><ns2:servingStatus>Inactive</ns2:servingStatus><ns2:startDate>20100730</ns2:startDate><ns2:endDate>20991231</ns2:endDate><ns2:budget><ns2:period>MONTHLY</ns2:period><ns2:amount><ns2:amount>3333.3333</ns2:amount></ns2:amount><ns2:deliveryMethod>STANDARD</ns2:deliveryMethod></ns2:budget><ns2:biddingStrategy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:ManualCPC"/><ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus>OPTIMIZE</ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus><ns2:stats><ns2:network>ALL</ns2:network><ns2:statsType>Stats</ns2:statsType></ns2:stats><ns2:statusReason>FutureDT</ns2:statusReason></ns2:entries><ns2:entries><ns2:id>3000065</ns2:id><ns2:name>Sample Campaign API Report Testing 1</ns2:name><ns2:status>ACTIVE</ns2:status><ns2:servingStatus>Inactive</ns2:servingStatus><ns2:startDate>20100802</ns2:startDate><ns2:endDate>20991231</ns2:endDate><ns2:budget><ns2:period>MONTHLY</ns2:period><ns2:amount><ns2:amount>3333.3333</ns2:amount></ns2:amount><ns2:deliveryMethod>STANDARD</ns2:deliveryMethod></ns2:budget><ns2:biddingStrategy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:ManualCPC"/><ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus>OPTIMIZE</ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus><ns2:stats><ns2:network>ALL</ns2:network><ns2:statsType>Stats</ns2:statsType></ns2:stats><ns2:statusReason>FutureDT</ns2:statusReason></ns2:entries><ns2:entries><ns2:id>3000066</ns2:id><ns2:name>CampaignSridRevewSB</ns2:name><ns2:status>ACTIVE</ns2:status><ns2:servingStatus>Active</ns2:servingStatus><ns2:startDate>20100810</ns2:startDate><ns2:endDate>20991231</ns2:endDate><ns2:budget><ns2:period>DAILY</ns2:period><ns2:amount><ns2:amount>10000.0</ns2:amount></ns2:amount><ns2:deliveryMethod>STANDARD</ns2:deliveryMethod></ns2:budget><ns2:biddingStrategy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:ManualCPC"/><ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus>OPTIMIZE</ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus><ns2:stats><ns2:network>ALL</ns2:network><ns2:statsType>Stats</ns2:statsType></ns2:stats></ns2:entries><ns2:entries><ns2:id>3000067</ns2:id><ns2:name>Campaign #3000067</ns2:name><ns2:status>ACTIVE</ns2:status><ns2:servingStatus>Active</ns2:servingStatus><ns2:startDate>20100811</ns2:startDate><ns2:endDate>20991231</ns2:endDate><ns2:budget><ns2:period>DAILY</ns2:period><ns2:amount><ns2:amount>10000.0</ns2:amount></ns2:amount><ns2:deliveryMethod>STANDARD</ns2:deliveryMethod></ns2:budget><ns2:biddingStrategy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:ManualCPC"/><ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus>OPTIMIZE</ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus><ns2:stats><ns2:network>ALL</ns2:network><ns2:statsType>Stats</ns2:statsType></ns2:stats></ns2:entries><ns2:entries><ns2:id>3000068</ns2:id><ns2:name>Campaign #3000068</ns2:name><ns2:status>ACTIVE</ns2:status><ns2:servingStatus>Active</ns2:servingStatus><ns2:startDate>20100811</ns2:startDate><ns2:endDate>20991231</ns2:endDate><ns2:budget><ns2:period>DAILY</ns2:period><ns2:amount><ns2:amount>10000.0</ns2:amount></ns2:amount><ns2:deliveryMethod>STANDARD</ns2:deliveryMethod></ns2:budget><ns2:biddingStrategy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:ManualCPC"/><ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus>OPTIMIZE</ns2:adServingOptimizationStatus><ns2:stats><ns2:network>ALL</ns2:network><ns2:statsType>Stats</ns2:statsType></ns2:stats></ns2:entries></rval></ns2:getResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

What tells you that it's empty? DOMDocument::loadxml() will return false it there's an error, rather than an empty object.

Anyway, when I run this code ($doc is the mile-long single line of xml you posted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($doc);
$node_list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('totalNumEntries');
$node = $node_list->item(0);
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

The output is "6", as expected.

Comment: thanks for your hint, I used a var_dump to print the content:

and the result of this var_dump is:
object(DOMDocument)#17 (0) {
}

Comment: Sry for late answer, but I stumbled over this question. This is the default output you will always get for DOM-objects, even if the object has content. This is because, the content is hidden to php script side. You will have to use the objects Methods to get the correct status information.